# strptime date format needed for date like `12/06/16 19:33`

Tags: python, python-3.x, strptime

I created this format to be used `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'` for parsing texts like `12/06/16 19:33`. However, I get exception. Here is a code snippet -

```
datetime.strptime('12/06/16 19:33','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

What is the correct format that I can use to validated date time is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
datetime.strptime('12/06/2016 19:33',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

or try this use `y` instead `Y`:

```
datetime.strptime('12/06/16 19:33',"%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: @bosari, i edit the code block is this your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify to :

```
datetime.strptime('12/06/16 19:33', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```